# Left join - joined tables double results

Tags: php, mysql

this is my query with two left joins (tried to join bcompany - main table WITH bpoint, bug):

```
SELECT cName, sName, uNaslov FROM bcompany c LEFT JOIN bpoint p ON c.companyID = p.companyID LEFT JOIN bug b ON c.companyID = b.companyID WHERE c.companyID='$cID'
```

First table `bcompany` is a main one, and there is **always exactly one** result row.

Both tables `bpoint` and `bug` relate to `bcompany` via the `companyID` column.
These two tables **will not necessarily have** any records.

My problem are doubled results of those two joined tables. I can understand multiple results for the main table, but not for the joined two.

*Table structure:*

**bcompany:**

```
companyID |       cName         |
---------------------------------
    1     | Mladi Tehnik d.o.o. |
```

**bpoint:**

```
pointID |      sName          | companyID |
-------------------------------------------
   1    |    Mladi Tehnik     |     1     |
   2    |    Pizzerija 5ka    |     1     |
   3    |    Gostilna Kekec   |     1     |
   4    |    Blejski tehnik   |     1     |
```

**bug:**

```
bugID | uNaslov       | companyID |
-----------------------------------
  1   |  Testna 1     |     1     |
  2   |  Testna 2     |     1     |
  3   |  Mickino kolo |     1     |
```

Results example:

```
bcompany:
Mladi Tehnik d.o.o.
Mladi Tehnik d.o.o.
Mladi Tehnik d.o.o.
Mladi Tehnik d.o.o.
Mladi Tehnik d.o.o.
Mladi Tehnik d.o.o.
Mladi Tehnik d.o.o.
Mladi Tehnik d.o.o.
Mladi Tehnik d.o.o.
Mladi Tehnik d.o.o.
Mladi Tehnik d.o.o.
Mladi Tehnik d.o.o.

bpoint:
Mladi Tehnik
Mladi Tehnik
Mladi Tehnik
Pizzerija 5ka
Pizzerija 5ka
Pizzerija 5ka
Gostilna Kekec
Gostilna Kekec
Gostilna Kekec
Blejski Tehnik
Blejski Tehnik
Blejski Tehnik


bug:
Testna 1
Testna 2
Mickino kolo
Testna 1
Testna 2
Mickino kolo
Testna 1
Testna 2
Mickino kolo
Testna 1
Testna 2
Mickino kolo
```

The results i want (every existing result only once):

```
bcompany:
Mladi Tehnik d.o.o.

bpoint:
Mladi Tehnik
Pizzerija 5ka
Gostilna Kekec
Blejski Tehnik

bug:
Testna 1
Testna 2
Mickino kolo
```

Comment: Add create table script to understand the db structure

Answer (score 0):

The result is ok. If there were only one entry in the `bpoint` column the result would be inconsistent because there is one *"Mladi Tehnik d.o.o."* with *"Mladi Tehnik"* and the exact same one without a `bpoint` entry.

Comment: How can i get rid of those duplicates in bpoint and bug table?

Comment: You don't have to. The result is absolutely fine. You have to handle thin in your code.